# jquery function starts before the page is loaded

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a php page, wich hase some external links to js files in the head, and on body I have some selectable elements from jquery(sometimes I do not have them, because thouse elements are generated if the user is login). The problem is in the javascript I wrote, I get this error: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'disableSelection'. Even if I put a ".sortable" element in the php, I still get this error. In html looks like it has no problem with that and works fine. The code that gives me the error is this:

Sorry for my english. I can put the hole code if you want but is too big. I think the problem is because the javascript is loading too fast or before of the html is generated.( I tried to put a variable in the js and that function under a if() but is not working)

The javascipt(scripturi.js):

```
 var logat=0;

$(document).ready(function() {

    $( ".sortable0" ).sortable();
    $( ".sortable0" ).disableSelection();

    $( ".sortableIt" ).disableSelection();
    $( ".sortableIt" ).sortable(
    {
        stop: function(event, ui) 
        {
            for(var i=0;i<ui.item.parent().children().length;i++)
            {
                 var x =ui.item.parent().children()[i].id;
                 //update items din acest sertar
                //updateItemServer(x,i)
                //alert(x+ " " + i);   
            }       
        }
    });

    $( ".sortable" ).disableSelection();
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable({ stop: function(event, ui) {reparaZindex();}});

});


function updateItemServer(x,i){
//alert(x+" "+i);

}

 function incarca(){
    $(document).ready(function (){
            $.getJSON("http://students.info.uaic.ro/~calin.chifan/api/compartiment/list.json", function(data){ 
                var html = [];
                /* loop through array */
                $.each(data, function(index, d){   
                    addCompartiment(d.nume_comp,d.id);
                });
            }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ /* assign handler */
                alert("error occurred!");
            });
    });
}

function addCompartiment(nume,id){
     $("#sortable0").append('<ul class="sortable" id'+ +'>');
}


 function updateIndexServer(x,y){
 //alert(x+" "+y);
 //trimite id-ul x si pozitia y
 }

function reparaZindex(){
    $.each($(".sortable > li"), function() 
    {
        if($(this).find('.sertar')[0])
        {
            $(this).find('.sertar').eq(0).css('z-index',(500-$(this).index()*2));
            updateIndexServer($(this).find('.sertar')[0].id,$(this).index())
        }

        if($(this).find('.sortableIt')[0])
            $(this).find('.sortableIt').eq(0).css('z-index',(501-2*$(this).index()));               
    }); 
} 

window.onload = function() {
    //incarca();
    //reparaZindex();
}
```

It's strange that in the html I don't have this problem. After the user is logedin I want to call a function that will append some ul (.selectable) elements but so far it can't even notice that there are some elements. If you want I can give you a link to the page I work.

A little bit of the php:

```
    <?php
    ini_set('session.save_path', '/tmp/');
    session_start();

        $logged=0;
        if(isset($_SESSION['autentificat']))
        {
            if($_SESSION['autentificat']==1)  
            $logged=1;
        }
      $user= $_COOKIE['user'];
    echo'
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Proiect Web</title>

      <meta charset="utf8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>jQuery Dropdown Login Freebie | The Finished Box</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="login.js"></script>
            <script src="scripturi.js"></script>
            <script src="dulap.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


            <script src="login.js"></script>
            </head>'
            ;

      if($logged==1)
      {
        echo'<body onload="loadYeslog()">';



      }  
  else {
    echo'<body onload="loadNoLog()">';
  }

echo
    '<div class="mainbar">

                <div id="loginContainer">
                <div id="loginButton"><span style="display:block;width:48px;height:27px; ">Login</span></div>
                <div id="logoutButton" class="barbutton" style"cursor:pointer;"><span>Logout</span></div>';



      if($logged==0) 
      {
        echo'<div id="welcomeLabel" class="barbutton"><span>Not Logged in!</span></div>';
      }
      else
      {
        echo '<div id="welcomeLabel" class="barbutton"><span>Welcome '.$user.' !</span></div>';

      }

echo '<div style="clear:both"></div>
                <div id="loginBox">                 
                    <form id="loginForm" action="autentificare2.php" method="POST">
                        <fieldset id="body">
                            <fieldset>
                                <label for="username">
                  Username</label>
                                <input type="text" name="user"/>
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset>
                                <label for="password">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" name="password"/>
                            </fieldset>
                            <input type="submit" id="login" value="Sign in" />

                            <label for="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />Remember me</label>
                        </fieldset>
                        <span><a href="recovery.php" style="color: white;">Forgot your password?</a></span>
                         <div id="regbut"><span>New user ? </span></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div id="regbox">
                           <form id="registerform" action="register.php" method="POST">
                            <table style="margin-top:10px;">

                                <label for="Dusername">
                                  REGISTAR FOARM!!! </label>


                                <tr>
                                   <td>
                                   <label for="Dusername">
                                   Username: </label>
                                   </td>
                                   <td>';
                                   ?>

                                   <input type="text" name="Duser"   placeholder="Introduceti numele de cont dorit" onblur="javascript:semnaleazaExistaNume (this.value, '')"  />
                                   </td>
                                   <td>
                                   <span class="ascuns" id="eroareNume">Numele deja exista, alegeti altul... </span>
                                   </td>
                                </tr>


                                <tr>
                                  <td>
                                  <label for="Dpassword">
                                  Password: </label>
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                 <input type="password" name="Dpassword"/>
                                 </td>
                                 </tr>

                                <tr>
                                <td>
                                   <label for="Demail">
                                  E-Mail: </label>
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                 <input type="text" name="Demail"/>
                                 </td>
                                 </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                 <input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" />
                                  </td>
                                 </tr>
                             </fieldset> 
                            </table>
                            </form>
                </div>
            </div>   
    </div>
  <div class="box">
    <ul class="sortable0" id="sortable0">
        <ul class="sortable" id="sortableColona1">
        <li id="sertar1" style="z-index:10"> 
            <img id="sertar11" class="sertar" ONCLICK="openS(this)" style="position: relative;z-index:500;aligh:center;" src="img/sertar1.png">
            <ul id="ui items1" style="z-index:501;position:relative;visibility:hidden;" class="sortableIt" >
              <li id="item1" class="ui-state-default">1</li>
              <li id="item2" class="ui-state-default">2</li>
              <li id="item3" class="ui-state-default">3</li>
              <li id="item4" class="ui-state-default">4</li>
              <li id="item5" class="ui-state-default">5</li>
              <li id="item6" class="ui-state-default">6</li>
              <li id="item7" class="ui-state-default">7</li>
              <li id="item8" class="ui-state-default">8</li>
              <li id="item9" class="ui-state-default">9</li>
              <li id="item10" class="ui-state-default">10</li>
              <li id="item11" class="ui-state-default">11</li>
              <li id="item12" class="ui-state-default">12</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the jQuery code in the $(document).ready(); function and then it will run only when the page loads like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

This will make sure it only runs when the page and all the DOM elements have completely loaded.

**UPDATE:**

Can you add the following code in your HTML head section as you need jQuery UI to make the relevant method call:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Make sure you include it after you have loaded jQuery, so the head section code should be like:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="login.js"></script>
<script src="scripturi.js"></script>
<script src="dulap.js"></script>
<script src="login.js"></script>
```

First thing is to make sure you have jQueryUI loaded since the method you are calling belongs to its API. We can take things forward from there!

Comment: Even then, what if I do not have any .selectable elements? I will get an error as well.

Comment: can you share complete code? have you included jQueryUI since the method that is not working for you belongs to jQueryUI API.

Comment: Ok, in a secound i will put the complete code, I don;t know about jQuerUI

Comment: you should try adding jQueryUI in your HTML <head> section.

Comment: I've put it in the head. Take a look up. Seams to be something else, I've uploaded the code and still the same error (look again on the code above)

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not include jquery ui anywhere! You just include JQuery, not the JQuery UI part. The Sortable is part of the jquery ui. Check it out at: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/ If you include it correctly it is not problem if you have a element on your page which responds to the selector or not. Just make sure, that you include the correct library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add jQueryUI. Please add below code to after jquery section.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @raducup Good. It's my pleasure.